# Header not incorporating all Images

Tags: html, css

I have placed an image within the `<header>` tags of my code, but the image is cutting right through it and the header is not expanding to the size of the image. The code goes something like this:

```
<header>
<img src="the_image.png" style="position:relative; align:right; float:right; width:40%; height:inherit" />
</header>
```

The header Style is as follows:

```
header
{
position:relative;
width:Auto;
height:auto;
max-height:239px;
min-height:inherit;
background:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Does it have anything to do with the position I am using? Why does the header simply not expand to come to the size of the image (which is the maximum height that I have given)?

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: It's because  your image is floated. adding `overflow: hidden;` to the container would fix it. Or there are [other methods](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Comment: overflow: hidden; is not working. I have added a fiddle here:  jsfiddle.net/z707x908

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`width: Auto;` is incorrect, it should be `width: auto;` Have you tried this?

Update:
As a comment before mentioned, you might have missed `overflow: hidden;`

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/z707x908/1/

Comment: It would be really great, if you could create a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)... I have created a fiddle, but I could not understand, what should happen: http://jsfiddle.net/1rzr038r/

Comment: @user3409468 - How can you say it's not working when it's clearly working in Lorzenz's fiddle?

Comment: Yes thanks, it is working now. I had in fact missed overflow:hidden;